# Combine DataGridCheckBoxColumn and DataGridTextColumn to one class?

Tags: c#, silverlight

From what I used in Telerik's GridView control, I can dynamically add a column DataGridColumn (forgot the extact class name) into the GridView, if the binding object is bool then it will use CheckBox to display, otherwise will use text to display.

Now I switched to use Silverlight's basic DataGrid control, I wonder if I can write a single class and do the same thing?

```
GridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridColumn(){Binding = new Binding("boolType"), Header="Bool Type"});
GridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridColumn(){Binding = new Binding("StringType"), Header="String Type"});
```

Thanks in advance.

King

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, but you will need slightly more than just a "single class". The technique is based on `DataGridTemplateColumn` where we will choose a template for each column based upon it's type.

1) You will need a helper class which will decide which template to choose:

```
public class ColumnTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        switch (newContent.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "Boolean":
                ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["BooleanDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
                break;
            case "String":
            default:
                ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["StringDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know, this could be done better but i think it's simple enough to notice what it's all about, it can be extended, optimized etc.

2) Add the Content Templates to your `App.xaml` File, they might look like this (simple example, you might want to modify them):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanDataTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

3) Now we can setup the `DataGrid`. One caveat is that we'll need to define our columns, we cannot use the `AutoGenerateColumns` feature. Ok, here is the example code. First, add the Namespace where the `ColumnTemplateSelector` (see 1.) was defined, to your `MainPage.xaml` (or whereever you need it):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySilverlightExample"
```

Assumed that our class (call it "Person") has three columns: "Name", "Age" and "IsMarried" (is `bool` actually), your table looks like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfPersonItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ColumnTemplateSelector Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ColumnTemplateSelector Content="{Binding Age}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ColumnTemplateSelector Content="{Binding IsMarried}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Maybe there is a shorter syntax how it can be written but this is how it would basically work, just tested it here and worked like a charm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow, this is so detail, I am not so familiar with using template, so your example really help a lot! I will try it out once I am back to office next week! Thanks!

Comment: Data templates are one of the best Xaml UI features. In WPF there is a better support and so will be in Silverlight 5. The `ColumnTemplateSelector` is just a current workaround.

Comment: Instead of defining each column in xml, I made a class that inhert DataGridTemplateColumn and apply the CellTemplate dynamically when I set the Binding property that I have defined.  Now I can do both dynamically adding column with one class and use auto generate column at the same time.  Thanks for your idea!